# Random lockups with my new build - gigabyte z77x-d3h

Tags: freeze

Random lockups happens all the time, and it's not related to high loads on CPU. Everything just freezes - no BSOD.

My PC specs:

```
gigabyte z77x-d3h (bios - F15)
intel i7 3770k (stock cooler)
DDR3 Corsair Vengeance 8GB (xmp)
creative sb value
samsung ssd 830 128gb (connected to 6gb port sata slot)
THERMALTAKE SMART PSU 550W
```

OS: Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit

Answer (score 0):

Check that the heat sink is properly bonded to your i7 and that the fan is running.  Modern processors have a thermal cutoff.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to take it in stages. Start by cutting back to minimum bootable configuration - CPU+Mem+Video

1) Check CPU Temp, as has been mentioned above.

2) Connect a CD or bootable USB and check the memory (MemTest or similar)

3) Connect HD and boot. Torture Test with Prime95 or similar.

4) Add components back one at a time, (Sound Card etc) and torture-test until you find the one that causes lockups.